# Resource leak from an array

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have following class:

```
class estimate
{
    public:
        estimate();
        ~estimate();
        double *tHanning;
}

estimate::estimate()
{
    tHanning = NULL;
    tHanning = new double [1000];

    for (int m=0; m<1000; m++)
    {
        tHanning[m]=(0.5-0.5*cos(2.0*PI*(m+1)/(1001))); 
    }
}

estimate::~estimate()
{
    delete [] tHanning;
    tHanning = NULL;
}
```

I am not sure why C++ Memory Validator shows resource leak in the constructor when I assign "new" to the variable.

Can somebody please help me?

Edit: How I sue the above class:

```
class HBMain
{
    public:
        HBMain();
        ~HBMain();
        bool Init();
        estimate *objEstimate;
}

HBMain :: HBMain()
{
    objEstimate = NULL;
}

HBMain :: ~HBMain()
{
    delete objEstimate;
    objEstimate = NULL;
}

bool HBMain :: Init()
{
    ....
    objEstimate = new estimate();
    ....
}
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message. Also, how do you create instances of `estimate`?

Comment: How do you use the `estimate` class? You might want to read about [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: Thanks all. I have edited and put the code on how I use the estimate class.

Comment: This is why it's recommended to use `std::vector` instead of doing manual memory management.

Comment: You may have made a mistake while adding your code: Why are you using objEstimate as it was a pointer, it's not declare as Estimate* !

Comment: Sorry guys, I have edited again. I have indeed declared it as a pointer.

Comment: How many times do you call the init function?

Comment: @doctorlove I just call this Init once.

Comment: Is this a simplification of the code? For example, is estimate inherited without a virtual destructor?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson This is a simplification but it is not inherited.

Comment: Many peopel have pointed out to use vector::double? What are the advantages and disadvantages? Will it not take more memory?

Comment: @chintans `std::vector<double>` consumes no more memory than an array of `double` of the same size. Its advantages are that you don't have to worry about manually managing memory. Its disadvantage is... well... I don't know really. Can't think of anything off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution, why not simply change your pointer by a vector of double ?

You will avoid headaches about memory leaks.

Edit: For the HBMain class, you can also changed your naked pointer by a smart pointer (shared_ptr) from C++11 or the Boost library and delete the destructor. And so you will not have to implement all the boilerplate code.

But, do you really need a dynamic allocation for the HBMain property ?

Comment: Many thanks. If I use vector::double, will it not take more memory?

Comment: Yes a bit more and it will also be a bit more slower. But you have to keep in mind that C++ is really fast so for the vast majority of code, that's not a big deal.

In advantage : no memory leak headache and that's a huge plus.

And it's the same of the smart pointers.

Comment: Thanks again. Let me convert all the pointers to vector and see how much memory it takes. Cheers.

Comment: Also, of course you will not have to implement boilerplate code.

Comment: You only have to change tHanning to a vector<double>. For objEstimate, it will be a shared_ptr<estimate>. If you can not use C++11, you can still use smart pointers by using the Boost library.

Comment: This is just one issue. I have many more such pointers! not much but enough to leak plenty of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Both your `estimate` class's constructor and destructor seem fine (you dynamically allocate memory with `new[]` in the constructor, and `delete[]` it in the destructor).

But I think you may have problems during **copies**.

In fact, your class has *default* copy constructor and `operator=`, but the default behavior is *not* good in this case; in fact, the default behavior is just member-wise copy, but copying the raw pointer `tHanning` data member is a "leaktrocity".

Either disable copy constructor and `operator=` (e.g. declaring them `private` in C++98/03, or using the new `= delete` C++11 syntax), or give a proper implementation for them.

Proper implementation should do *deep* copy of the owned array (with proper deletion of any previously allocated array).

I think the best thing you can do is to use **`std::vector<double>`** instead of the raw pointer.

If you are really such highly constrained on the (relatively small) overhead of `std::vector`, then consider using a *smart* pointer like `std::unique_ptr`:

```
#include <memory>   // for std::unique_ptr

class estimate
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<double[]> tHanning; // <--- SMART pointer

public:
    estimate()
        : tHanning(new double[1000])
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < 1000; m++)
        {
            tHanning[m] = (0.5-0.5*cos(2.0*PI*(m+1)/(1001))); 
        }
    }

   // No need to define destructor - smart pointer automatically deletes its owned stuff
};
```

In this way, the class will be *movable* but *not copyable*, and you will incur almost zero overhead if compared to the raw pointer case.

---

As a bouns reading, consider the [**Rule of Three**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) in C++.

---

Again, in your `HBMain` class, don't use a *raw* `estimate *objEstimate` pointer data member.
Instead, use **smart pointers** like:

```
class HBMain
{
  ....
private:
    std::unique_ptr<estimate> objEstimate;

   // Again, no need to define a custom destructor for deleting objEstimate.
   // std::unique_ptr will do proper deletion *automatically*.
};
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. The use of number 1000 was just for an example. How do I modify the code in constructor, where I get the size from another calculation? Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. For your new question: you can use **`unique_ptr::reset()`** method, something like this: `const int count = GetProperSize(); tHanning.reset( new double[count] );`.

Comment: Thanks again for reply. So should I do the same as above, if want to change the size anywhere else in the code?

Comment: I did exactly as above and C++ Memory Validator still think it leaks memory :(